# Python: How to get data from other defined function to the other?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this program:

```
def NoOfPeople(people):
    if people.isdigit() and (int(people)>=1) and (int(people)<=1000):
        return True
    else:
        print('invalid')
while True:
    people = input('No. of people:')
    if NoOfPeople(people):
        break
```

How do I use data from it to a new defined function as I have this menu and program which I am stuck at right now on how to continue to get the data from the previous one.It is to check if the selected room can accommodate to the number of people that are entered in NoOfPeople(people). So how can I compare the number of people with which room it can accommodate:

```
Room
[1] Room A (10 person)
[2] Room B (30 person)
[3] Room C (50 person)

venue = input('Please select a venue:')
def validateVenue(venue):
    if venueList == '1':
        (what should I continue from here?)
```

Help and suggestion please as I am new in using python.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty open ended but I will try and help you out.

in general you can pass a variable / data_structure to another function and return it out of the function back to whatever called the function like this...

```
def function_name(var1, var2):
   var3 = var1*var2 
   return var3

new_var = function_name(3, 5)
print(new_var)
```

> > output 
> >     15

1) I don't know what venuList looks like you might want to make a Key value pair (dictionary)

```
def select_venue(num_of_people):
    #this is your venue key value dictionary, IE your available venues and their size
    venues = {10:"Venue Small Conf Room" , 30:"Venue Ballroom", 50:"Venue Large Conf Room", 3:"Venue Office"}
    venue_options = []

    for occupancy in venues:
        if occupancy >= num_of_people:
            venue_options.append(occupancy)

    venue = min(venue_options)
    venue_name = venues[venue]


    print("Please Use {} for your event with {} people (max occupancy {})".format(venue_name,num_of_people, venue))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    people = 4 #change this value to test
    select_venue(people)
```

your output should look like this

> Please Use Venue Small Conf Room for your event with 4 people (max
>   occupancy 10)

You will notice the key is the max occupancy of a venue and the value is the name of the venue.

You should also take note they don't have to be in order (small office is last)

Comment: Did you give this a try?